# understanding and implementing custom class in java

Tags: java, class, if-statement, methods, accessor

I am very new to class programming and I am trying to implement the class I have created in my application program so I have some questions on how to do so I will specify below...

[**Inside application program**] the user will enter a `int`, lets say `int number`.

This `int number` will than be sent as a parameter to my class `myClass` to an accessor method in `myClass` titled `numberSearch` where this method will see if `number` exists inside an array. Where I am having the most trouble is...

[**inside the application program**] checking to see `if(number == any of the array integers)`

which is where shows my complete lack of understanding of getting use to using my own classes. please please help me understand how to do this! Thanks guys! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read a bit more about Java classes like Orion is suggesting.

If you require any specific help you should at least show us your code and highlight any errors and areas you need help with.